# how to export the figure to color eps in matlab

Tags: matlab, eps

I have a plot in Matlab needed to save the eps format. If I use the interactive menu in the figure to do so, everything is going all right, the exported eps is good. But if I use the following command

```
saveas(gca, 'myplot.eps','psc2');
```

But if I do in this way, the exported eps is not clipped and the margin is too big. How to save the eps without margin in the program? Thanks.

BTW, if I use the following code instead

```
saveas(gca, 'myplot.eps','eps');
```

then the output eps is clipped but it is black and white instead of color.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The following works for me:

```
print -depsc myplot.eps
```

Answer (score 34):

Just combine @mola's answer with what you've got already:

```
saveas(gca, 'myplot.eps','epsc');
```

Note the **c** in `'epsc'`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what you are looking for:

http://www.mathworks.se/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23629-exportfig

Comment: thanks. I am just wondering if there is any way to do that with built-in matlab function.